# TGPUObjectsPool memory leak on shutdown in Delphi 11.1 FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

Running 11.1, I get this `TGPUObjectsPool` error on shutting down a simple basic FMX 2D app under Windows 64-bit (Release mode). First time I have seen this error.

Just running a blank form with `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True` in `project.dpr` results in this error on closing.

There are no components on the TForm.  Just run and close.   It makes me wonder what kind of QA is done for a Delphi release if a basic empty project can close with such memory leaks.

Any solutions to get rid of this error?

```
---------------------------
Unexpected Memory Leak
---------------------------
An unexpected memory leak has occurred. The unexpected small block leaks are:

9 - 24 bytes: TGPUObjectsPool x 1    
89 - 104 bytes: TObjectDictionary<System.TClass,System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList<FMX.TextLayout.GPU.TReusableObject>> x 1
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau oh thanks for the link!  I googled and didn't find a single link to TGPUObjectsPool .  I guess maybe they should consider having their samples include the ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown=True.  After all, it's samples, so the extra link won't hurt.

Comment: "It makes me wonder what kind of QA is done for a Delphi release if a basic empty project can close with such memory leaks." That kind of rant isn't appropriate in a SO question, but I ask the same question. I absolutely understand your frustration, and I have recently been rather active in Embarcadero's Jira about quality issues. The good thing is that I feel that Embarcadero *is listening* and improving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
uses
{$IFDEF VER350} // 11.x
  FMX.FontGlyphs,  FMX.TextLayout.GPU,
{$ENDIF}

finalization
{$IFDEF VER350} // 11.x
  // RAD Studio 11 memory leak
  TFontGlyphManager.UnInitialize;
  TGPUObjectsPool.Uninitialize;
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @NBuyer This actually works elegantly without changing the source of FMX.TextLayout.GPU.pas   -  I'm using this for now. Thanks for the post!   Just a small note to include a blank initialization section above finalization for code to compile.

Answer (score 6):

> It makes me wonder what kind of QA is done for a Delphi release

A lot, actually. Months of beta testing, lots of fixes and internal builds.

This issue was actually reported during testing, but only just a couple of weeks ago, after it was too late to fix for the final release. But, this leak (and others) have been reported publicly after 11.1 was released:

[RSP-37596 FMX TFontGlyphManager's UnInitialize not called in finalization](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-37596)

[RSP-37600 Unexpected Memory Leak in TGPUObjectsPool](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-37600)

[RSP-37613 Memory leak in an application that only serves forms](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-37613)

[RSP-37656 Memory leak in FMX (simple project)](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-37656)

And there are other similar memory leaks (in `TFontGlyphManager`, `TBehaviorServices`, etc), so hopefully this will get fixed in the next update.

> I guess maybe they should consider having their samples include the ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown=True.

Funny, because I see a similar report for that, too:

[RSP-37598 Make RTL, FMX and VCL developers turn on memory leak checking by default](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-37598)

Comment: I think quite a number of people share the sentiments that memory leak checking can be added by default; it's easy to turn it off anyway.

Comment: "A lot, actually. Months of beta testing, lots of fixes and internal builds." That might be true, but there is a "but". I had to make a FMX app a few months ago, and during the first week of development, I "accidentally" discovered about 50 FMX bugs, some quite nasty. Most I discovered within an hour. (For instance, every time you press the Win key on your keyboard, the currently selected Object Inspector field gets replaced by a [ bracket.) About half of them I reported to Embarcadero, and some were fixed in 11.1. So maybe there is testing going on, but I do understand the OP's frustration.

Comment: Or the 10.3 titlebar which disintegrated into several parts with random locations on the screen when you maximized the IDE. That I discovered within a second the first time I started the 10.3 IDE. (I am autistic, so maybe "normal" people don't notice things like that.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, I wonder if you would make for a good beta tester - if you actually are a interested.

Comment: @UweRaabe: I would love to help out if asked.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand users with an active subscription are openly invited to join betas before releases.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Okay, I use CE at home and am not responsible for the license at my company. That explains why I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it (as a workaround) including ShareMem as first unit in uses in my project source.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).